# Get Subfolder for a folder using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to access Subfolders for a folders. Below is my Code.

```
ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();   
                conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;   
                conn.Username = _userName;   
                conn.Password = _password; 


ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + selectedServer.IPAddress + "\\root\\cimv2", conn);
ManagementObjectSearcher servSearcher2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(theScope, new ObjectQuery(@"ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name ='c:\\users'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent "));
ManagementObjectCollection servObj1= servSearcher2.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in servObj1){}
```

Its Giving an error "Invalid object path". Any idea what I m doing wrong?

Comment: `Subfolders for a folders` Are you talking about file system here? What's your test folder structure? What do you expect to get out of it? Is it recursive (i.e. also include subfolders of subfolders)?

Comment: i know its recursive, what i want is top folder of this directory.

Answer (score 0):

in the windows Operating systems the ".." folder is a linked folder to the parent folder and will take you up one level

you could call a loop that continues to navigate to ".." until you find the folder name your looking for.  A 'top folder' of any folder would be your drive letter (root dir).  Be careful though as ".." is found in every directory (except your root dir) so ".." would be relative to the folder your currently in.